# How to do Weighted Averaging of n conscutive values in an Array

Tags: matlab, weighted-average

I have a 900×1 vector of values (in `MATLAB`). Each 9 consecutive values should be averaged -without overlap- result in a 100×1 vector of values. The problem is that the averaging should be weighted based on a weighting vector of `[1 2 1;2 4 2;1 2 1]`. Is there any efficient way to do that averaging? I’ve heard about conv function in `MATLAB`; Is it helpful?

Comment: This is just 1D convolution followed by choosing 100 values with step 9

Comment: Why are the weights a 2d matrix?

Answer (score 0):

`conv` works by sliding a kernel through your data. But in your case, you need the mask to be jumping through your data, so I don't think `conv` will work for you.

If you want to use existing MATLAB function, you can do this (I have to assume your weighting matrix has only one dimension) :

```
kernel = [1;2;1;2;4;2;1;2;1];
in_matrix = reshape(in_matrix, 9, 100);
base = sum(kernel);
out_matrix = bsxfun(@times, in_matrix, kernel);
result = sum(out_matrix,1)/base;
```

I don't know if there is any clever way to speed this up. `bsxfun` allows singleton expansion, but maybe not dimension reduction.

A faster way would be to use [mex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html). Open a new file in editor, paste the following code and save file as `weighted_average.c`.

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *in_matrix, *kernel, *out_matrix, base;              
    int niter;
    size_t nrows_data, nrows_kernel;                   

    /* Get number of element along first dimension of input matrix. */
    nrows_kernel = mxGetM(prhs[1]);    
    nrows_data = mxGetM(prhs[0]);

    /* Create output matrix*/
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mwSize)nrows_data/nrows_kernel,1,mxREAL);

    /* Get a pointer to the real data */
    in_matrix = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    kernel = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    out_matrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    /* Sum the elements in weighting array */
    base = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows_kernel; i +=1)
    {
        base += kernel[i];
    }

    /* Perform calculation */
    niter = nrows_data/nrows_kernel;
    for (int i = 0; i < niter ; i += 1)
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j < nrows_kernel; j += 1)
        {
            out_matrix[i] += in_matrix[i*nrows_kernel+j]*kernel[j];
        }
        out_matrix[i] /= base;
    }    
}
```

Then in command window , type in

```
mex weighted_average.c
```

To use it:

```
result = weighted_average(input, kernel);
```

Note that both `input` and `kernel` have to be M x 1 matrix. On my computer, the first method took 0.0012 second. The second method took 0.00007 second. That's an order of magnitude faster than the first method.

Comment: Except that he'll have to run the mex function approx a half million times for the mex version to be faster than the reshape version once you take into account the minimum of 10 minutes it'll take him to figure out how to compile mex :P

Comment: Well, that's why I listed it as method 2 :P